# Android Programm add video at the start of my app

Tags: android, video, startup

I want to add at the startup of my app a video 5 sec. 
How can i do this? I
 have to create a new activity? 
and a new layout?

Comment: I would really advise against running a video every time your app starts: It turns users away because they can't use your app instantly and it uselessly drains the battery. Also think of the increase in APK size -- smaller APK means faster download/update, means happier users. Do you really need that video?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a new activity and layout and add this to the activity definition in manifest.xml.  This will stop the user being able to press back to go to the video..

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a new activity with [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist), like Simon said. If your video is something like tutorial, you should store a variable in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for checking "is this a first launch or not". If it is not a tutorial, I would advice you to add in your Settings screen a checkbox "Show Splash Screen or not". Let the user choose it.

Comment: No My video will run at the startup of my app and it is something like bootanimation.

Comment: I want to add the choise that if the user touch the screen the video stops and the screen gets at the main xml.

Comment: BootAnimation or something like that need when app asynchronously working and preparing some data for main activity. I realized that this is not your case. For stoping video, when user touch the screen use setOnTouchListener for your Layout or videoView.